# How can I create the picker so that in addition to the text I can display an uiImage .png

Tags: swiftui, picker

[image]

[image]

How can I create the picker so that in addition to the text I can display an uiImage .png

Answer (score 0):

instead of just Text(...), use this:

```
                HStack {
                    Image("your-uiimage-name")
                    Text("your-text")
                }
```

Comment: Thanks I had done so, but it does not bring me the image in detail, how should I do?

Comment: sometime with images you have to do this:  Image("your-uiimage-name").renderingMode(.original).resizable().frame(width:20,height:20)

Comment: It does not select it and in detail you do not see any image or text

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wVNb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0GFc.jpg)

It does not select it and in detail you do not see any image or text, and when it saves it does not report anything

Comment: This is not an answer. Please update your question with these additional details.

Comment: I agree this is not an answer. I think she does not understand SO process. Also please post code not images of code.